# Tapir - List type for input parameter not working

Tags: scala, circe, tapir

I am defining an API endpoint using tapir which goes like this

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import sttp.model.StatusCode
import sttp.tapir.json.circe._
import sttp.tapir._

val endpo: Route[List[String], String] =
      endpoint.post
        .in(Versions.current / Paths.api / "_api")
        .in(jsonBody[List[String]])
        .out(jsonBody[String])
        .errorOut(Errors.Common)
```

When I try calling this endpoint with json like

```
[
    "sds",
    "hgj"
  ]
```

It returns me bad request or invalid body as response.

Can someone please help me with this. I do not know what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: What is your backend?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik its scala

Comment: I think tapir currently supports http4s, finatra and akka http. You're using probably one of them.

Comment: Yes I am using akka http

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik It should not be that hard, this sounds like a very basic problem but I am unable to solve it.

Comment: @ArjunKarnwal did you ever solve this? I am now having just the same problem!